# Athena CTAS replacing null values in tables with \N

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

When I use Athena CTAS to generate CSV files, I found that null values in the Athena table are replaced by "\N".
How do I get it to just leave these values as empty columns?

The CTAS query I'm using is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name WITH (format = 'TEXTFILE', field_delimiter=',', external_location='s3://bucket_name/location') AS SELECT * FROM "db_name"."src_table_name";
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default token for `NULL` for `LazySimpleSerDe`, and CTAS does not expose any mechanism for changing it unfortunately.

If you'd rather have empty fields for your `NULL` values you have to ensure they are all empty strings, e.g. `… AS SELECT COALESCE(col1, ''), COALESCE(col2, ''), …`.